# generate X.509 or PEM and privat key (RSA, PEM) from two certificates from GeoTrust

Tags: ssl, openssl, rsa, private-key, pem

I've got following lines from GeoTrust:

```
Web Server CERTIFICATE
-----------------

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----


INTERMEDIATE CA:
---------------------------------------

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Is it possible and what should I do to generate X.509 or PEM file and privat key (RSA, PEM) file from this?

Thanks!

Comment: Certificate consists of a public key and some more information but from these you can not generate private key.

Comment: You generated the private key, not GeoTrust. The private key should already be on your computer.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Is a PEM-encoded certificate.  If you extract that and save it into `yourcert.pem` (or `yourcert.cer`) you'll have the PEM certificate saved as a single file.  You can do the same with the intermediate(s), if you like.

Some applications want a combined data file where you take the PEM encoded certificate and then follow it (in the same file) with the PEM encoded private key.  Wherever you created your certificate signing request you should still have a key hanging around.

```
cat yourcert.pem your.key > yourcertwithkey.pem
```